# What does ComPtr.As() do?

Tags: c++, com

I am working on learning DirectX 12 from some examples but I am having trouble understanding what does the ComPtr.As() method does.

```
ComPtr<ID3D12Device> device;
ComPtr<ID3D12Device> device2; 

// Do Stuff with Device
device.As(&device2); // What does this do?
```

Comment: [This description](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr#obtaining-new-interfaces) covers some points, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21171916/1270789) shows it saves you doing `QueryInterface`, ugly casts and reference counting. *Why* one needs to do `QueryInterface` is a separate question...

Comment: It means that you need to find better examples.

Answer (score 4):

Where did you find this example code? It looks fishy. This is kind of a nonsense use of `As`. It's equally silly if you expand it to the underlying `QueryInterface`:

```
hr = device->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS(device2) );
```

In fact, your code would be better written as:

```
device2 = device;
```

Typically you'd use `As` to obtain a new interface from an existing interface. For example with Direct3D 11, you create the device as a Direct3D 11.0 interface and then have to `QueryInterface` the 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, and/or 11.4 versions to use them:

```
ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(D3D11CreateDevice(..., device.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf());

ComPtr<ID3D11Device2> device2;
hr = device.As(&device2);
if (FAILED(hr))
    // Do whatever handling you do if the system doesn't support 11.2
```

Another common use with Direct3D 11 is dealing with the debug interfaces which may not be present:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    ComPtr<ID3D11Debug> d3dDebug;
    if (SUCCEEDED(device.As(&d3dDebug)))
    {
        ComPtr<ID3D11InfoQueue> d3dInfoQueue;
        if (SUCCEEDED(d3dDebug.As(&d3dInfoQueue)))
        {
#ifdef _DEBUG
            d3dInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_CORRUPTION, true);
            d3dInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, true);
#endif
            D3D11_MESSAGE_ID hide [] =
            {
                D3D11_MESSAGE_ID_SETPRIVATEDATA_CHANGINGPARAMS,
                // TODO: Add more message IDs here as needed.
            };
            D3D11_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER filter = {};
            filter.DenyList.NumIDs = _countof(hide);
            filter.DenyList.pIDList = hide;
            d3dInfoQueue->AddStorageFilterEntries(&filter);
        }
    }
#endif
```

It's also important to not ignore the HRESULT return value that comes back from `As`. You should use `SUCCEEDED` or `FAILED` macro, or a fast-fail like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).

See [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).

Comment: I came here googling for the same question...that code is out of MSDN's "So you want to learn DirectX" code examples 