# Why do I need to query interface?

Tags: c++, com

In a question I asked: [What does ComPtr.As() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214778/what-does-comptr-as-do)

I found that the As() method Query Interface but why do I need to do that? What is the point of Query Interfacing?

Comment: This is very broad. You should try to locate an introduction to COM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's **COM** is a language-agnostic *component* technology. A *component* is a separately compiled object, which might reside in a different process or even on a different computer. The latter possibility is called **DCOM**, short for Distributed COM.

The COM way of accessing a component relies on a binary level memory layout, which incidentally is exactly how early Visual C++ laid out polymorphic objects, with a vtable pointer first in each object. Every COM object is derived from the `IUnknown` class, which adds three virtual member functions, namely two for reference counting and one for interface querying. This incidentally is also the layout used for Java Native Interface, and it's used in e.g. XCOM for Unixland.

The COM designers believed that *implementation inheritance* was ungood, so instead each object offers one or more distinct pure **interfaces**, collections of virtual methods. To obtain a pointer to a given interface for a given object, at the lowest level you pass an 128-bit statistically unique interface identifier to the `IUnknown` interface's method that queries for an interface. Remember that while COM's binary level layout is designed for C++, the technology as such isn't especially C++-friendly: it's language agnostic, and so you have to query for interface at run-time, rather than having those interfaces as part of the C++ type of an object.